# Efficient way to animate a div absolute position within a container

Tags: html, css, optimization, animation, css-position

I'm currently working on a website that dynamically builds a "city" made of little building blocks. The buildings and city props are all positioned using "position: absolute" and "left". They all lay on a container div (also with "position: absolute"), which in turn is laid on another div (with "position: relative") that limits the visible part using "overflow: hidden". In order to position the user camera, I update the container div's "left" CSS property, effectively moving the content left or right. So far, so good.

The problem is that, on less capable browsers and machines, the animation is really slow. I'm currently using a 30ms timer that'll call a tick function, and this tick function will process the user input, calculate the new left and update the CSS accordingly. This is, naturally, causing several browser reflows and sometimes the animation really looks sluggish.

You can check it out in here: <[website](http://dev.lqdi.net/porto-shopping/)>

The script: <[script](http://dev.lqdi.net/porto-shopping/application/shopping/views/js/script.js)>

Anyone has any suggestions on how I may optimize this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up optimizing this by replacing absolute positioning with scroll positioning, and using the requestAnimationFrame trick on Mozilla and Webkit to improve framerate performance. Here are some pointers to whoever encounters this problem as well:

About the requestAnimationFrame() function (efficient async animations on capable browsers):
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.mozRequestAnimationFrame

Getting and updating a div's scroll position in jQuery:
http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/

Answer (score 1):

use [jQuery.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

This will allow you to accomplish what you want and it's probably way better optimized than what you currently have.

Update: Here's my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/LeNx3/)!

Hope it helps.

Comment: The problem is: I need the camera to move left or right for as long as, say, the mouse is over the arrow buttons or the user is pressing the left or right keys.

Comment: You can do that with `jQuery.animate`, it allows you to stop animations too, you can add an `.animate()` on the `:hover` event (first check that it isn't running) and then `.stop()` when it loses focus

Comment: The :hover event will only be fired once when the mouse is over. I need that the camera moves as long as the mouse is over, and then stop smoothly when the mouse leaves. Furthermore, if I used the :hover selector on the jQuery.animate, it'd be implied that I wanted to animate the element being hovered, and that is not the case.

Comment: On `:hover` you `animate` (if it isn't `:animated`), that starts the animation asynchronically. Then when it loses focus you `stop()`. I'll try to update with an example.

Comment: The problem is that the animation is just executed once in your example. In my case the camera needs to continue going left for as long as the cursor remains over the left arrow. Thanks for your tip, though!

Comment: @DfKimera it does exactly what you want, you just have to set, instead of `left: +=300`, `left: =300`, so it either reaches that position, or it stops when you move away from the focus. When you move away from the `Hover me` div, the animation stops...